# How to move text up in Tab Bar?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have Tab Bar in bottom of app and every Tab Bar item has title.

How can I move every this title up or down?

Answer (score 3):

Solution:

```
 UITabBar *tabBar = self.tabBarController.tabBar;

 UITabBarItem *item0 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0];

 item0.titlePositionAdjustment = UIOffsetMake(10, 5);
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot (unless its iOS5 or later). You'll have to do it custom.

Comment: Ok. Can you pls give me any example for doing it?

Comment: i assumed you are targeting below iOS 5.x (i never did something like this, so I'd probably search SO for such examples)